# Stored Payment Method in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, payment-methods, customer-account

I have used authorized.net payment method and its working fine.

In account dashboard I have a link Payment Methods which says `"You have no stored payment methods".`

I want to ask how it works means I didn't find any option to add payment methods or enable it from admin side.

Please guide me.

Thanks